# Vendor Creates Content Publishes it on our site VIA RSS - Does this effect our SEO?

Tags: rss, seo

We outsource content creation and they vendor we use published the content on an XML feed that we pull from. Does this effect our SEO?

The feeds URL is not ours so I want to say yes but I cannot be sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Google don't index XML feeds, so I'd actually assume you are okay provided

- The content does not appear on anyone else's site.
- You are embedding it in your page server-side so that it appears as normal html to a web crawler.

The bigger issue for me would be what happens when your contract expires - can the vendor run off and take your site's content with them?  Also, if their site goes down then yours will also lose the content (unless you are caching).